# Why Does the Script Throw an "sort_by: undefined method" error?

Tags: ruby

I am going over the basics of Ruby, and according to some docs I mistakenly believe this should work:

```
#Write a function that sorts the keys in a hash by the length of the key as a string.

hash = { abc: 'hello', 'another_key' => 123, 4567 => 'third' }

array = hash.keys.to_s

sorted_array = array.sort_by(&:length)

puts sorted_array
```

But I'm getting the output:

```
sort_by: undefined method `sort_by' for "[\"abc\", \"another_key\", 4567]":String
```

Comment: Hint #1: What does the `s` in `to_s` stand for? Hint #2: It does not stand for "array".

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = { abc: 'hello', 'another_key' => 123, 4567 => 'third' }
array = hash.keys.to_s
```

Ah no. You end up with one string (the string representation of the entire array of keys). Try this:

```
p sorted_array = hash.sort_by{|key, value| key.to_s.length }
```

which takes every key-value pair, converts the key to a string and returns its size, and sorts on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `hash.keys.to_s` - `#to_s` produces a String representation of any given object. Strings are not Enumerables, and thus do not have the `#sort_by` method.

Instead, you probably want `array = hash.keys`, which will return an array of the Hash's keys.

Comment: OP can avoid the intermediate `array` by going straight to `sorted_array = hash.keys.sort_by &:length`.

Comment: That unfortunately won't avoid the allocation, only the local assignment of the first allocation. `hash.keys` allocates one array, then `sort_by` produces a second one, even if you chain them.

Comment: True, but it will allow freeing up the allocation ASAP.